# Legends in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm working on a project which requires me to create a legend
legend has 2 values and both of them are text
I'm able to create a legend and other stuff but I'm not able to get the same design
Below is the code that I'm using .

Problem:
The current output Is not able to handle long texts.
The design of legend has texts in different color(i.e; labels("A","B"...) in blue in the rest in black )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>      
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{"legend_value":"A","value":8,"label":"test1"},
            {"legend_value":"B","value":15,"label":"this is a veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy long text"},
            {"legend_value":"C","value":20,"label":"test3"},
            {"legend_value":"D","value":10,"label":"test4"},
            {"legend_value":"E","value":25,"label":"test5"},
            {"legend_value":"F","value":1000,"label":"test6"},
];
for (var i=0;i <data.length;i++){
data[i]["legend_value"]=String.fromCharCode(65+i)
}
console.log(data)
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 500, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([0, width-50]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 300 300")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value; })])
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.legend_value; }));
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);


var bar_height=Math.min(Math.ceil((height/data.length)-data.length*1),45);
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter()
    
    bars.append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.legend_value); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", "#056DFF")
      .attr("d",  function (d) {
                    console.log("y.bandwidth()",y.bandwidth())
                    return rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)) , x(d.value), y.bandwidth(), 5);
            });
    
function rightRoundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  return "M" + x + "," + y
       + "h" + (width - radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + radius
       + "v" + (height - 2 * radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + -radius + "," + radius
       + "h" + (radius - width)
       + "z";
}

bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "legend_value")
            //y position of the legend_value is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
             return Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)+y.bandwidth()/data.length) + Math.ceil(bar_height/2);
             })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", d => x(d.value)+20)
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', '#DCDCDC')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            //.style("text-anchor", "middle");



  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));





// add legend rect gray
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "legend_text")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ 
    return  450 ;
})
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return 0 })
  .attr("rx", "5px")
  .attr("width", margin.left + margin.right-100)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("stroke", "darkgray")
  .attr("fill", "#F8F8F8");
  
var legend_text = svg.selectAll("legend_text")
  .data(data)
  .enter();

legend_text.append("text")
  .attr("class", "legend_text")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ 
    return  470 ;
})
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return 20 + i*20 })
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d["legend_value"] + "  " + d["label"] ;
  });

</script>
</body>
```

**Current Output**
[image]

**Expected Output**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a necessary requirement, it'd be easier to have the legend be a regular html element. You could have 2 elements in a container, with 1 wrapping the svg, and the other containing the legend.

I've created a codepen of what I'm talking about here: https://codepen.io/OSquiddy/pen/OJmQxzx

If this is not an option for you due to constraints, I'd recommend repurposing [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) code to fit your requirements (ie. text-wrap inside for an svg `<text>` element).

Comment: can you tell me how i can i get the legend below with same size as the chart

Comment: i would like them to be one below another

Comment: I have tried this --->flex-wrap:wrap; but didnt find it useful

Comment: Your're on the right path. Keep ```flex-wrap: wrap``` on ```.container```. But that won't have any effect unless the contents of that element are going beyond the full width of the container. Since ```.legend``` and ```.chart-container``` both have a ```width: 50%```, they fit within ```.container```. To have them both stacked one on top of another, give them a width of 100%

Comment: I cant do that as i want another simalar graph to be on right side

Comment: ?? So you want 2 bar charts, with one legend below them? Or you want 2 bar-charts side by side, with their respective legends below them?

Comment: That's not an issue. Do what I said above. Then wrap `.chart-container` and `.legend` in another div. Give it a name `.chart-1` or something. Similarly create a `.chart-2`, with its own chart and legend. Give both `chart-1` and `chart-2` a display of flex, and `width: 50%` This way you'll have 2 charts in one container, side by side, with both having their legends below them